# Calling a function response in another function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

How do i call this response in another function? This is my code

```
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
      // Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
      // the past seven days.
      gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
        'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
        'start-date': '7daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
        'dimensions' : 'ga:date'
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);      
      })
      .then(null, function(err) {
          // Log any errors.
          console.log(err);
      });
}
```

I want to pass the response of this function to another function.

For example:

```
$scope.sample = function(){
  //call the response of function queryCoreReportingApi
};
```

Comment: is the "other function" calling this function, or is this function calling the "other function" - it's not clear from your question

Comment: `myFunction(response);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: *I want to pass the response of this function* But that function has no response. You need to return its value. Then you don't "call a function response in another function"; you **access** that value, which is a promise, with `queryCoreReportingApi().then(response => $scope.sample = response)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is not completely clear from your question, but I'm going to take a crack at it anyway.

Firstly, before answering your question, I have concerns about the way your code is formed above-- in particular, the two `.then()` blocks you have chained.  While I don't know the specific API you are using, generally promise-type APIs allow `.then()` methods to be passed two arguments-- the first a function to be called if the promise succeeds, and the second a function to be called in the case of an error.  So I am suspecting that perhaps what you meant to type was:

```
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
      // Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
      // the past seven days.
      gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
        'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
        'start-date': '7daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
        'dimensions' : 'ga:date'
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);      
      }, 
      function(err) {
          // Log any errors.
          console.log(err);
      });
}
```

This is just a hunch, but I think you should check that.

Now in regards to the question you asked-- unless I am missing some important information, you should be able to access any method available in the same scope (or higher) as the `queryCoreReportingApi` method and pass it the response from the success method of your `.then`.  For instance:

```
function myCustomFunction(data) {
    //do some stuff with the data
}

function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
      // Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
      // the past seven days.
      gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
        'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
        'start-date': '7daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
        'dimensions' : 'ga:date'
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        myCustomFunction(response);      
      }, 
      function(err) {
          // Log any errors.
          console.log(err);
      });
}
```

Does this answer your question?  If not, please provide more details as to the specifics of your inquiry.

**EDIT:** I see from your edit above that it looks like you are using Angular.  In that case, I am also going to surmise that the pasted method you have provided is inside of a service that is being called from the controller.  If that is the case, you can expand your `queryCoreReportingApi` method to accept a callback method as the second argument, to be called in the event of a success, like so:

```
// in your controller
$scope.sample = function (data) {
    // manipulate the returned data
}
// call the service
myReportingService.queryCoreReportingApi(profileId, $scope.sample);
```

And then later, in your service:

```
//in your service
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId, callback) {
      // Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
      // the past seven days.
      gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
        'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
        'start-date': '7daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
        'dimensions' : 'ga:date'
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        callback(response);      
      }, 
      function(err) {
          // Log any errors.
          console.log(err);
      });
}
```

(I also do see that you are referring to "calling" the response of the success.  That sort of suggests that the response is itself a method you want to call.  I think that is just a mistype on your part, but if that is the case, it is as simple as just calling it when you receive it, like so:

```
.then(function(response) {
    response();
});
```

But I doubt this is what you meant.)

Comment: im sorry for my question not clear. for example i have this code. $scope.sample = function(){
  //call the response of function queryCoreReportingApi
};

Comment: myReportingService is not defined

Comment: The chained `.then()` calls in the original code should be ok for ES6 promises (and other similar implementations).